# Retrieve data from custom table

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to use the following code to retrieve data from a custom table in WordPress:

```
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, name FROM mytable" );
```

The result set is empty, even though there is data in the table. Getting data from the database for the WordPress internal tables works without a problem.

For example, the following works without a problem:

```
$posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type='post' ORDER BY comment_count DESC LIMIT 0,4");
```

Any thoughts on how to diagnose the issue?

Comment: Did you trying accessing `$wpdb->mytable` or `wp_mytable`?

Comment: Is `mytable` the real table name (not some reserved mysql word by accident)?

Comment: The table name is not reserved is correct. I tried it with both, `$wpdb->mytable` and `wp_mytable` as well. Same result. The function returns a zero size array. I'll have to see if there are any errors MySQL is potentially returning.

Comment: @jbsound Does the wordpress mysql user have sufficient permissions for your custom table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a problem with your SQL statement, an error will get `echo`ed out - where that goes in WordPress, I don't know.

WordPress does have a Error Logging widget you can install to help you debug your problem: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/error-log-monitor/

This should explain how to set up the logging so you can see where the problem is coming from.

Comment: Looks like the WordPress install referenced the wrong database, which did not have that particular table installed. Using `$wpdb->show_errors();` output the error statement returned from MySQL.